# Dropdownlist in Kendo Ui

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui

I have a dropdownlist which contain `divisionName`, but I want the `divisionID` to be in dropdownlist. Anyone know about it?

```js
// dropdownList

function divisionDropDownEditor(container, options) {
  $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
      autoBind: false,
      dataTextField: "divisionName",
      dataValueField: "divisionID",
      dataSource: {
        type: "POST",
        transport: {
          read: "http://vx-dev.ehors.com:8480/najwa/getDivisionName.php"
        }
      }
    });
}

// getDivisionName.php file


<?php
    ##############################################################
    #### Fetch data from database and display into JSON format ###
    ##############################################################

    $getcheckbox = (isset($_POST['c1']) ? $_POST['c1'] : "all");   // by default select *

    $propertyID="1";
    include("../EHORS.pdo.php");
    $ehorsObj = new EHORS();
    $ehorsObj->EHORS_CONNECT($propertyID);

    $sql = "SELECT  divisionID, divisionName FROM tblAdmDivision";

/*  $sql = "SELECT  tblAdmDepartment.divisionID, tblAdmDivision.divisionName 
            FROM tblAdmDepartment
            INNER JOIN tblAdmDivision
            ON tblAdmDepartment.divisionName = tblAdmDivision.ivisionID";*/

    if ($getcheckbox == "true") {
            $sql .= " WHERE active = 'y' ";
        } 

        //$sql .= " ORDER BY 2 ASC " ;  // ordr by segmentName

    $array = array();   

    // /* PDO */
    $GetResult = $ehorsObj->FetchData($sql, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);

    while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()){
            $array[] = $row;
    }


    header("Content-type: application/json");

    $result = json_encode($array);
    echo $result;       

?>
```

Comment: What will happen if you swap         dataTextField: "divisionID",
                            dataValueField: "divisionName", .......... Can you check?

Comment: I've check about it, all data of dropdownlist become undefined

Comment: Can you check over [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/EfUhIrAP) I have checked It's getting Id if I swap. follow the link and [fix](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index) your mistake

Comment: Alrights, thank you. But, i have another problem which database SQLyog did not save data in the dropdownlist? i don't know how to get the right query for able database save the data.

Comment: Database Table Department: departmentID (PK), departmentName, departmentEmail, divisionID (FK). Based on this, i have to call divisionID to get divisionName. Do you have any idea, how the query is?

Comment: Look into getDivisionName.php file. you have to return the data from there.

Comment: i've do that, but still the database can't get the divisionID or divisionName

Comment: can you show that Php file.